# How to continue process while looping still running in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

STR="animated banner"
CLR=$(tput setaf 4)
BLD=$(tput bold)${CLR}
BLK=$(tput blink)
RST=$(tput sgr0)
DLY=0.3

animate() {
printf '%s\r' "$STR"
sleep "$DLY"
while :; do
    for ((i=0;i<${#STR};i++)); do
    l=${STR:0:i};
    r=${STR:i}
    printf '%s%s%s%s\r' "${l}${BLD}${r^}${RST}"
    sleep "$DLY"
    done
done
}

animate

printf "I want to continue this while looping above still or keep running"
```

How can I continue the script while the loop is still running?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What you need is a multi-threaded process. idk bash very well, but you may have to call a new side script to achieve it.

Comment: I have tried with source and & but, the process still stuck on looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the function asynchronously in the background. As the function doesn't exit by itself, you need to save the PID of the background process, so you can kill it on demand later.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR="animated banner"
CLR=$(tput setaf 4)
BLD=$(tput bold)${CLR}
BLK=$(tput blink)
RST=$(tput sgr0)
DLY=0.3

animate() {
printf '%s\r' "$STR"
sleep "$DLY"
while :; do
    for ((i=0;i<${#STR};i++)); do
    l=${STR:0:i};
    r=${STR:i}
    printf '%s%s%s%s\r' "${l}${BLD}${r^}${RST}"
    sleep "$DLY"
    done
done
}

animate &
animPID="$!"

printf "I want to continue this while looping above still or keep running"
sleep 2
ls /   # example command to run while the function runs
sleep 1
echo foo
sleep 1
date   # another command
sleep 1
kill "$animPID"
wait
```

Notes:

- The final `wait` ensures the script ends after the function exits, not just after `kill` exits (in general the signal to the function and its reaction may be delayed for various reasons).
- `kill "$animPID"` kills the subshell executing the function, not its descendants (possibly running asynchronously in general). Your function does everything except `sleep` in the shell and `sleep` not being killed is not a problem because it exits by itself fast. With a more complicated function problems may arise.
- What the function prints and what the rest of the script prints may interleave and thus look ugly or be misleading. Note how `echo foo` doesn't overwrite your entire banner and makes a part of it remain in the line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, you save my time :)